# Google Maps Api V3:Make marker move automatically

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the tutorial in google maps code found here:
 http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html

and I am loading my markers from the mysql database.

What I want is to make markers move in an way that they represent the movements of a bus.

Is it possible?

Can it be done with polyline?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a simple matter of using [`Marker#setPosition()`](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker). As you get the new positions for buses, get a reference to the marker for each bus and update it's `LatLng` value. You might maintain an array of markers that you iterate over or some sort of a mapping between bus identifier and it's marker.

And I don't understand how you would represent the movements of a bus using a polyline - that doesn't make sense. However, if you want to update a polyline, then you might do it by updating the `path` MVCArray passed to create the polyline. According to the [documentation](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polyline):

> **path** *MVCArray.|
>   Array.*
>   The ordered sequence of coordinates of the Polyline. This path may be specified using either a simple array of LatLngs, or an MVCArray of LatLngs. Note that if you pass a simple array, it will be converted to an MVCArray Inserting or removing LatLngs in the MVCArray will automatically update the polyline on the map.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Thats what i was looking for my problem.

Comment: @Kosmik Glad it helped :) You might also consider accepting the answer, it'll stop this question from showing up as unanswered - see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)